# How to make Google Maps marker bounce again in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, event-handling, google-maps-markers, event-listener

I want my Google Maps marker to keep bouncing. When it is dragged, I want it to stop bouncing. When it has stopped being dragged, I want it to start bouncing again.

Here is the code:

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: 0, lng: 0 },
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    });

    marker.addListener('dragend', function () {
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    });

    marker.addListener('dragstart', function () {
        marker.setAnimation(null);
    });
```

The problem is that when I stop dragging the marker, it does the bounce animation once (for like a second) and then the marker doesn't keep on bouncing up and down like it did before being dragged.

I have the same problem in another function when I click on a marker and then click on it again (it bounces once after the second click and doesn't keep on bouncing).

It only does one bounce and stops, but I want it to keep on bouncing up and down on `dragend` (like it does before being dragged), rather than having one bounce and it stopping.

Any ideas why it's not continuing the animation and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a bug in the API.  Might be worth opening an issue in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/558438) pointing to this question.

You can work around it by using a `setTimeout` to restart the animation again:

```
marker.addListener('dragend', function() {
  marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  setTimeout(function() {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }, 1000);
});
```

- There seems to be some period of time when the previous animation is active, but ending, where it will only bounce once.
- The `animation_changed` event doesn't seem to help either (doesn't seem to fire when the previous animation stops).

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5zmsxk8c/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// The following example creates a marker in Stockholm, Sweden using a DROP
// animation. Clicking on the marker will toggle the animation between a BOUNCE
// animation and no animation.

var marker;

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {
      lat: 59.325,
      lng: 18.070
    }
  });

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
    position: {
      lat: 59.327,
      lng: 18.067
    }
  });
  marker.addListener('dragend', function() {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    setTimeout(function() {
      marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }, 1000);
  });

  marker.addListener('dragstart', function() {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
  });

  marker.addListener('animation_changed', function() {
    console.log(marker.getAnimation());
  })
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Might be worth opening an issue in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/558438) pointing to this question.

Comment: Looks like a bug indeed. If you remove the initial animation declared as a Marker option, then toggling the animation in the `dragstart`/`dragend` listeners (as OP did) works fine, but only once.